# Watching Hulu on 16.04 or 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, flash

I'm having trouble playing Hulu on Ubuntu. It started one or two months ago (it used to work before). I always watched it on Chrome.

Some time ago, after a couple minutes of playback, the CPU usage of Chrome would spike (this is a media computer, so I've only noticed it happening on Hulu but not on websites that play HTML5) and then the video will start stuttering and the whole system will become almost unresponsive.

I tried the following things:

- Firefox: after the initial ads, only the network logo appears and no video or sound. This is with `libhal1` and either regular `flashplayer` or `pepperflash` installed and enabled in alternatives. I also enabled the Protected Content setting in Firefox
- Chromium: It just complains that it cannot play protected content and to use Firefox
- Installed 18.04 (not from scratch, as I kept my home): things are exactly the same
- Reinstalled Chrome (purged and removed profile): no improvement
- Deleted as many `.config` files I could find regarding Flash and Hulu: no improvement
- Disabled Hardware Acceleration in Chrome: worse

I've found people with the same (or similar) problems online, but no solution.

Does anyone know what's happening? How to troubleshoot or solve? I'm out of ideas.